# xcode timePicker returns wrong time

Tags: xcode, datepicker, datetimepicker

I am having an issue with a time picker and cannot figure out what my issue is.  Here is my code;

```
timePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSDate *selected = [timePicker date];

NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                     @"The date and time you selected is: %@", selected];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Date and Time Selected"
                      message:message
                      delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes, I did."
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

So for example if I select the time 2:55 pm the alert returns "2012-08-14 19:55:37 +0000"

It has to be something super simple just cannot see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSDate has no concept of timezones. It just stores the neutral time information. So you have to correct your output to compensate.

You could create an instance of NSDateFormatter and then setTimeZone:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"..."];

//Timezone!
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"..."]];

NSString *dateSting = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add time interval difference between UTC and your country time zone you can achieve it by this:

```
(sender.date as NSDate).addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(NSTimeZone.local.secondsFromGMT()))
```